# How to add nextset of fragments without disturbing current fragments in FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

**Here's the code to add the fragments for first time`**

`if(mcursor==null) {
            items = (ArrayList) cnews.getItems();
            mcursor = cnews.getNextPageToken();

```
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {

            Fragment cm = ContentFragment.newInstance(i, items.get(i).getTitle(),
                    items.get(i).getImageuri(), items.get(i).getDate(), items.get(i).getPublsher(), items.get(i).getDescription());
            frags.add(cm);

        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(new ContentfragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), frags));

    }else{
        items = (ArrayList<News>) cnews.getItems();
        mcursor = cnews.getNextPageToken();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {

            Fragment cm = ContentFragment.newInstance(i, items.get(i).getTitle(),
                    items.get(i).getImageuri(), items.get(i).getDate(), items.get(i).getPublsher(), items.get(i).getDescription());
            frags.add(cm);

        }
```

**In else condition i want to add some more fragments after server call.How can i update the adapter without removing old fragments?**

**Please help me i am newbie in android development.
Thanks in Adavance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the crucial parts here is that you must call

```
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

on the adapter so that the underlying data structures are updated accordingly
including triggering a redraw of the ViewPager.
Also don't forget that `getCount()` must also return the expected number of elements (ie. no hardcoding values here)

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    List<String> tagList;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        tagList = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.

        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(tagList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return tagList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return "SECTION "+(position+1);
    }

    public void add(int position, String key)
    {
        tagList.add(position, key);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



}
```

[image: Two fragments added]
[image: four fragments added]

Comment: when i use add method first time it load all fragments.when i want add more fragments size goes 0 and activity start with newly added fragments.How can i solve this issue?

Comment: @RafiqAhmad your code is a bit confusing, I do not see your "add" method but as a general rule, UI flickers and disturbs UX everytime you call  "viewPager.setAdapter()" is it possible that you are calling that everytime you add fragments? You should do like in the code that I showed you, just call 'notifyDataSetChanged()' after you add each fragment

Comment: Thanks it works only issue is after loading more fragments activity starting from first fragment again. can you help me with that?

Comment: No problem, can you explain in more detail? You add fragments, and what happens next?

Comment: First i added 3 fragments.it works fine.when i am at second fragment i make server call and will add another 2 fragments. after this activity reloads and it stats from first fragment but i can that now there are 5 fragments.Actually i am using vertical viewpager so one fragment at time.I want to load the fragments continuously like inshorts app.

Comment: @RafiqAhmad the activity lifecycle should not be affected by server calls, or even by any ViewPager. Are you sure that it is the activity that is "reloading"? 
i see this line: mcursor = cnews.getNextPageToken(); // if this returns null when you reach the end of your available fragments, you IF condition if(mcursor==null) will be true, and you will be calling viewPager.setAdapter() which will cause a UX flicker making it look like a reload

Comment: initially my cursor will be null so i will access if condition code.Then after second server call i am using add method(else loop code). i have changed my code as reference to your example.updated adapter using notifydatasetchanged();.

Comment: Thanks you so much i solved it today silli mistake i was setting adapter in server response so it is everytime refreshing.

Comment: @RafiqAhmad eheh there is the setAdapter spoiling the party, glad to hear everything is working ;)